# How to auto fill data in an excel column by taking matching data from other columns

Tags: excel

This is the reference data from which i want to compare

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
8   h
9   i
```

No when i fill values in the first column like

```
3
5
7
2
4
1
9
9
8
```

i want second column to take values from first array and put matching values automatically. like

```
3   c
5   e
7   g
2   b
4   d
1   
9   
8
```

any solution ?

Comment: Sure, just use the `VLOOKUP` function...

Answer (score 0):

Put your table of values in **A1:B10**. Be sure to have your key values in column **A**

in column **D** put your new values (i.e. 3,5,7,2.. as in your example) and place the following formula into cell **E1**

`=VLOOKUP($D1,$A$1:$B$10,2,0)`

you can drag this formula down to show other values.